# java problem (read file and create objects)

Tags: java

I have a java problem I need to do and i'm not sure how to do it. This is the problem:

Your task is to complete the given program by writing a method named **readData** and a class named **Person**.
The readData method is written inside the Customers class. The purpose of the program is to read customer
information from a file called **customers.txt**, make a new object out of each customer and finally print the information of all customers on the screen.

In the file, each customer is stored on its own line. The file contains the name and social security number of each customer. The Person class has one String-type attribute that stores the person's information (name and social security number).

A toString method must be written inside the Person class, which returns the person's information. The readData method gets an array as a parameter in which the created persons are placed. The purpose of the method is to create an object out of each customer in the file and place it into the array. The method returns the number of people in the file.

That's the instruction (above) and below is the pre-made code that I can't edit (except after the "your code here" part):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Customers {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     
        Person[] people = new Person[100];
        
        int peopleAmount = readData(people);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < peopleAmount; i++) {
            System.out.println(people[i]);
        }
    }

    // Your code here
```

Example output:

```
James 030377-2651
John 111177-1731
Robert 161280-1822
Michael 121160-1362
William 141075-16
```

If too busy to give a full answer, some info on how to make it is fine too. The instruction text wasn't in english originally so sorry if it has weird grammar.

Comment: Well, how is information stored in `customers.txt`?  Nobody can answer without that information.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong There’s no more info than what it says on the instruction. The example output shows how they are printed I suppose. Also there’s this part on the instruction: ” In the file, each customer is stored on its own line. The file contains the name and social security number of each customer.” So the file probably just has each customer name followed by their number split into their own lines.

Comment: @Abra There’s no access to customers.txt for the problem. It requires me to build it using just the information written on the instructions. But I would guess the example output is how the text looks like in the file.

Comment: To add here, the file customers.txt exists, but I can’t view it. So reading the file would just work with `BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(”customers.txt”));` I would guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the contents of file *customers.txt* is the same as the example output in your question, here is my implementation. I'm guessing that you can only use classes that you have learned about and I'm also guessing that you have not yet learned about the stream API in java so hopefully the below code is acceptable within the limitations of your assignment.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Customers {

    private static int readData(Person[] people) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;
        if (people != null && people.length > 0) {
            try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("customers.txt");
                 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                    Person p = new Person(parts[0], parts[1]);
                    people[count] = p;
                    count++;
                    if (count >= people.length) {
                        break;
                    }
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Person[] people = new Person[100];
        int peopleAmount = readData(people);
        for(int i = 0; i < peopleAmount; i++) {
            System.out.println(people[i]);
        }
    }
}

class Person {
    String name;
    String ssn;

    public Person(String name, String ssn) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + ssn;
    }
}
```

Method `readData` must be a static method since it is called from method `main` which is a static method.

Method `readData` reads file *customers.txt* line by line. Each line contains a name followed by a single space and followed by a social security number. According to your example output both *name* and *social security number* contain no spaces. If that is not the case, then the above code will not work.

Method `split` will create a two element array from a line of the file. The first array element is the *name* and the second is the *social security number*. Then I create a `Person` object and place it in the `people` array.

Comment: Just had to change the `class Person` to `static class Person` since it was complaining on the line `Person p = new Person(parts[0], parts[1]);` that `Person` can't be referenced from a static context. After that it worked. Thanks.